# How to store user-specific data in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, data-storage

I am building tree component and I want to save it's state (expanded nodes etc) so I can recreate that tree state when component is loaded again. What are available mechanisms in Lightning for this?

Comment: Do you want to store the state just for the current session of the user or permanently?

Comment: @RedDevil For each user, but I don't want to use database for this

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [Platform Cache](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_cache_namespace_overview.htm) for this purpose.
In combination with server-side controller it will fit your desire.

Use [Session](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_cache_Session.htm#apex_class_cache_Session) cache to store data related to each user

Comment: Would you mind adding a few references or code examples. Google didn't find a single result showing how to use a custom Sesson cache to speed up Lightning components.

Answer (score 14):

You can use localStorage in Summer'17

```
window.localStorage.setItem('name', value);
var v = window.localStorage.getItem('name');
```

Comment: can you share a link where it says so? as there is bug related to Summer '16, that it is not fixed https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IYE6QAO

Comment: In my org ( summer'17) i'm using this approach, and it is working. "In Summer '17, LockerService is auto-activated for all orgs with no option to disable."

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy `localStorage` is working fine for me too (Summer '17 org). But what you suggested is better for this(question's) purpose.

Comment: window.sessionStorage.getItem ... doesn't work with data not created by Salesforce sessionStorage